# Filter Get-ADComputer where "Name -notlike" in Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

My goal is to get a list of AD computer objects not following naming conventions with the whenCreated property. I am trying to export out a HTML file using the following PowerShell function:

```
function get_bad_names
{
$result = Get-ADComputer -searchbase $OU
-Filter {Name -notlike 'name1' -and 
         Name -notlike 'name2' -and
         Name -notlike 'name3'} 
-Properties whenCreated | sort whenCreated

$result | ConvertTo-Html | Out-File $dir\badnames.html
}

get_bad_names
```

Is there a more elegant way of structuring the Name filter lines? We have over 40 lines of different "names." In other words, over 40 lines in my script say `Name -notlike 'name#' -and`

Ideally I'd like for the code to read from a text file and export out the same results.

FYI: this function works but it is not ideally written. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you require the `-notlike` operator, or will a simple `-eq` check suffice? Your code as it currently stands suggest an equality check is fine.

Comment: I am uncertain if `-notlike` is required since there are wild characters in the naming convention. 

For instance, the lines actually look something like this: `Name -notlike 'IT_*_*'`

Comment: Why not get all and remove what you don't want after-the-fact? (What are you really trying to do?)

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Because the `-Filter` parameter will use the provider's filtering.  It's an orders of magnitude faster than piping to `Where-Object`.  My domain has ~10,000 computers.  `Get-ADComputer -Filter * | Where-Object Name -eq $ComputerName` takes about 5 seconds.  `Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -eq '$ComputerName'"` takes about 9 milliseconds.

Comment: @BaconBits yes I understand that (you will see a number of my answers that make this exact point). It just seems an odd requirement and I wanted more information. In fact my suggestion would be very much like Mathias R. Jessen's answer (it's easier to use -LDAPFilter IMO).

Comment: @Bill_Stewart you've made an assumption that 5s is too long for the asker.

Comment: I haven't made any assumptions. I was asking for what the goal really is.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart The goal seems pretty self evident to me.  "Find all computers in a specified OU whose names don't match one of a set of patterns and report them in a file."  Most businesses have specific nomenclatures for servers, another for workstations, etc. Given that he has 40 such patterns, they might put location or department or model or make information in the host names. This is most likely simply "Find computer accounts that don't belong in this OU based on their name." or "Find computer accounts that don't match the organization's nomenclature."

Comment: You may be correct. I asked for more detail to rule out that the question might actually be an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could filter with a regular expression using `Select-Object` but then you should get all computers in the OU with the `-filter *`, and that might strain your network. I would do the filtering and if more properties are needed, run `Get-Computer` again only for the matches:

```
Get-ADComputer -searchbase $OU -Filter * |
? { $_.name -match "name\d{1,2}" } | # Match if string "name" is followed one or two digits
Get-ADComputer -property * # Get all properties for the computers if needed
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to filter the query, construct an LDAP filter:

```
# Define the names to exclude
$NamesToExclude = "Name1","Name2","Name3"
# Turn them into LDAP clauses in the form of "(!(Name=Name1))"
$LDAPClauses = $NamesToExclude |ForEach-Object {
    '(!(Name={0}))' -f $_
}
# Create a single query filter string with all the clauses from above
$LDAPFilter = "(&$LDAPClauses)"

$result = Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter $LDAPFilter -SearchBase $OU -Properties whenCreated |Sort-Object whenCreated
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a more elegant way of structuring the Name filter lines?

Not exactly.  You have a fairly limited set of operators when you use the `-Filter` parameter of commands in the ActiveDirectory module because it has to translate them all to LDAP filters.

However, you can do something like this:

```
$ExcludedPatterns = 'Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3'
$ComputerFilter = foreach ($Pattern in $ExcludedPatterns) { "(Name -notlike '$Pattern')" }
$ComputerFilter = $ComputerFilter -join ' -and '
Get-ADComputer -Filter $ComputerFilter
```

Now you can maintain a list of name patterns.

Keep in mind that the `-Filter` property is *not* a ScriptBlock on the ActiveDirectory commands.  They're all **Strings** and in spite of the documentation for these commands they should be written that way.  Writing them as ScriptBlocks will eventually cause you problems with variable expansion.

Compare:

```
$ComputerName = hostname
Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -eq '$ComputerName'"
Get-ADComputer -Filter { Name -eq '$ComputerName' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to everyone for their feedback. I was impressed how fast the responses were.

I was able to achieve my goal using regular expressions reading from a text file.

My code now looks like this:

```
[regex]$Expression = Get-Content $dir\regex.txt

function get_bad_names
{
$result = Get-ADComputer -searchbase $OU 
-Filter {Enabled -eq $true} 
-Properties whenCreated | Where-Object {$_.Name -notmatch $Expression}| sort whenCreated

$result | ConvertTo-Html | Out-File $dir\badnames.html
}

get_bad_names
```